# Find integer N which, added to its (decimal) reverse, equals M

Tags: algorithm, math, integer, logic

Let N be an integer. If N = 2536, the reversed N is 6352. If N = 1000000, the reversed N is 1.
We are given an integer M, where 1 <= M <= 10^(100000).
We need to find whether an integer N exists, where N + reversed(N) = M.

Any ideas, besides brute force ?

Comment: What's brute force here? Would it be brute force if you could do it in time proportional to `base * #digits`?

Comment: this can be done with pen and paper

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here I will describe briefly an algorithm. It should be noted that many details needed to be filled in.

The basic idea is to look at the first and last digit of `M` to determine the sum of the first and last digit of `N`, and then subtract this quantity from `M` to reduce to the case of a shorter number.

Let us call a number **good** if it can be written as `N + reverse(N)`.

(EDIT: in implementation, one will probably need a function `IsGood(M, k)` which judges whether `M` can be written as `N + reverse(N)` for some `N < 10^k`. But let's skip this detail for the moment.)

The algorithm for determining whether a given number `M` is good goes as follows:

Let `c` and `d` be the first and last digit of `M`, and let `R` be the middle part. That is, `M` has digital expression `cRd`.

There are two cases:

- `c` is not equal to `1`
- `c` is equal to `1`

---

In the case where `c` is not equal to `1`, the digit `c` cannot be a carry. This is the **normal case**. Now look at `d`.

If `d` is equal to `c`, then `M` is good if and only if `R` is good.

If `d` is equal to `c - 1`, then there is a carry from `R` to `c`, so `M` is good if and only if `1R` is good in the **carry case** (see below).

If `d` is equal to anything else, then `M` is not good.

---

In the case where `c` is equal to `1`, there is the additional possibility that `c` is a carry.

Let `e` be the first digit of `R`, and write `M` as `1eTd`.

If `d = 9` or `e < d`, then the carry case is not possible.

(EDIT: this is wrong, the case `d = 9` is possible if `e = 0`.)

Otherwise, the carry case is possible if and only if `(e - d)(T - 1)` is good.

If either the carry case hold, or the normal case hold, then `M` is good.

---

Example:

Let us start with `M = 12001`.

Since `c = 1`, there is the normal case and the carry case.

In the normal case, we have `d = 1`, so we need to test whether `200` is good. For `M = 200`, we have `c = 2` and `d = 0`, so the number `200` is not good, hence the normal case for `M = 12001` fails.

In the carry case, we need to test whether `(12001 - 11000 - 11) / 10 = 99` is good. For `M = 99`, we have `c = 9` and `d = 9`, so this again reduces to whether `0` is good, which obviously is true. Hence the carry case holds.

The conclusion is then `M` is good.

---

Time complexity:

With some detailed arguments (which I don't want to present here), it can be proved that the algorithm runs in `O(log_10(M))` time.

Comment: What would be the case if R is empty? Take M=11

Comment: I got to the same solution. Also, since N has 6 digits (or the reverse of N does), M must either have the form `dddddd` (d = 1..9) or `1dddddd` (carry). `1ddddq` is a carry only if  `q = 1` (if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: @RishitSanmukhani I didn't write down all the details, but from the example it should be clear that we put `R = 0` if it's empty.

Comment: @WhatsUp can you tell  how the carry case works there is a bit confusion in it

Comment: The answer is actually a brief idea. In fact, you should write a function `IsGood(M, k)`, which returns `True` if and only if `M` can be written as `N + reversed(N)` for some `N < 10^k`. To calculate `IsGood(M, k)`, you just follow the idea of the answer, noting that the first and last digit of `M` can determine the sum of the first and last digit of `N`, hence reducing the length of `M`.